# kafka Protocol parse failure

Tags: apache-kafka

[image]

Why protocol parse failure? When I consume message

Comment: Please don't include screenshots -- they are not searchable. Please replace with inline text.

Comment: In addition, be more explicit in what you are doing, describe you setup.